# When do you use this expression 'I am not a fan of '

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I understand the meaning when it is said like

> 'I am not a fan of Indian food or horror movies'

Here, you are a fan of *things* like movies, food etc.

but I do not understand why it is correct to say

> 'I am not a fan of negativity'.

'negativity' is not a tangible thing. Can we use 'fan' this way?

Comment: What is it you don't understand? Please clarify. **Negativity** - the expression of criticism of or pessimism about something. (google search definition)

Comment: I'm sorry my English isn't good enough to tell you what I wanted to say. I know the word negativity means. What I 'm trying to say is I don't get it why it is correct to say in English because the word a fan is  someone who likes a particular thing. Negativity is intangible thing

Comment: Where did you get the idea that _thing_ refers only to tangible things? _"Liberty is the one thing you can't have unless you give it to others."_ (Wm A. White)

Comment: It's just a more idiomatic way of saying "I do not like".

Comment: When you say "I am not a fan of ...." you are also implying that the thing is something people might be a fan of. So by saying "I am not a fan of negativity" the denotation is that you don't like negativity, but the connotation is that there are *some people* around who do like negativity. So it can be a veiled criticism.

Answer (score 11):

Colloquially, you can be a fan (or not a fan) of anything, abstract or concrete, tangible or intangible.

When it's used colloquially, **be a fan of** implies "like".

> *I'm a fan of Tom Cruise.* ~ The speaker is a fan of the actor. They surely like the actor.
>   *I'm not a fan of spicy food.* ~ The speaker doesn't like spicy food much.

---

Here is a good example showing that the expression "a fan of" can be used with virtually anything. It's from the movie *Edge of Tomorrow* (the quote is from [www.moviequotesandmore.com](http://www.moviequotesandmore.com/edge-of-tomorrow-quotes-1/)):

> *[as they drive along the main road in France]*
>   Cage: You don’t talk much.
>   Rita: Not a fan.
>   Cage: Of talking?
>   Rita: Not a fan of talking, no.

It just means that Rita doesn't want to talk (with Cage) in that scene.

---

So, your *I am not a fan of negativity* simply means: I don't like negativity.

Answer (score 5):

Aw! You can be a fan of *someone* or *something* as well! So, it's fine to say that you are a fan or not a fan of **something**.

[Check the definition:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fan#fan-2)

> *A person who has a strong interest in or admiration for a particular person or **thing***.

The *thing* could be tangible or intangible.

So, when you are not a big fan of *negativity*, you don't admire/like negativity.

However, in my personal opinion, I'd avoid using the word 'fan' there. I'd say - 'I don't **favor** negativity (of any kind).'

However, *negativity* should be explained for better clarity.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this expression is used in a formal context.

You can use it with anything you don't like I guess.

Not being a fan of negativity simply means that you don't like being negative. It means you are a positive and optimistic person.

Answer (score 1):

You don't always use "I am not a (big) fan of X" for things like food or movies. You broadly use it for ideas/ideologies you hate or dislike.

> I am not a (big) fan of ***negativity***.

It means you are against negativity, you don't like people who are *negative*, or you are not a negative person depending on context.

> I am not a (big) fan of ***those people***.

You don't want to explicitly state that you hate those people. Depending on context, it could show your racism, homophobia or xenophobia, etc.

Comment: Hey, I'm a big fan of Indian/Italian/Mexican food is absolutely okay. And so is I'm a big fan of Bond movies! :)

Comment: @MaulikV Yes, I agree. Those are not ***negative*** sentences. I am a big fan of your answers. :)

Comment: Jumping straight from "I'm not a big fan of those people" to "I am secretly a racist" seems a bit excessive. That's a *possible* meaning, but it's by no means the only one, so the emphasis seems misplaced.

Comment: @NathanTuggy That's why I used ***depending on context*** and ***could***. What makes you think I jumped straight? I didn't. Show me why.

Comment: @Rathony: That's the only implication listed.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Not at all. There are ***homophobia*** and ***xenophobia***. You don't know the difference?

Comment: @Rathony: Sorry, I was referring to those too. I lump those all in as "socially unacceptable prejudice" for the purposes of e.g. this answer.